# Exchange serial messages via UART between 3.3V µController and 5V µController concrete (STM32F4 and ATMega 2560)

Tags: serial, atmega, uart, stm32

I would like to send messages from STM32F4Discovery board to Arduino Mega 2560 via UART.
How do I connect the Arduino to the STM32F4Discovery? Do I need any extra electronics? If I understand correctly, Arduino's UART has voltage level of 5V and the STM32F$ 3.3V.

Comment: How far apart are these boards? Do they share a common ground reference? What is the data rate?

Comment: The distance is under one meter and up to 115200 bit/s woud be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need wires. The STM32F4 has 5V-tolerant inputs and 3.3V is above the '1' threshold for the AVR. Connect ground and one or both pairs of TX/RX depending on whether you want bidirectional comms.